# Android project crashes when I use Physics World

Tags: android, box2d, andengine, physics

I am trying to develop a game with Andengine + Box2D. Everything is perfect but when I try to use Physics World , it crashes. If I don't use it,everything is perfect.  The line I am talking about is:

`physicsWorld = new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2(SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH,0),false);`

that in the `onLoadScene()` method.(sorry,I couldn't highlight it) Also,there is no error in the log. I added my log under the code too.

Here is my code:

```
package com.emredavarci.updatesistemi;

import org.anddev.andengine.engine.Engine;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.handler.IUpdateHandler;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions.ScreenOrientation;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.resolutionpolicy.FillResolutionPolicy;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.Scene.IOnSceneTouchListener;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.sprite.AnimatedSprite;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.sprite.Sprite;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.util.FPSLogger;
import org.anddev.andengine.extension.input.touch.controller.MultiTouch;
import org.anddev.andengine.extension.input.touch.controller.MultiTouchController;
import org.anddev.andengine.extension.input.touch.controller.MultiTouchException;
import org.anddev.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsConnector;
import org.anddev.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsFactory;
import org.anddev.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsWorld;
import org.anddev.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.Texture;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.TextureOptions;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.region.TextureRegion;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.region.TextureRegionFactory;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.region.TiledTextureRegion;
import org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity;

import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef.BodyType;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.FixtureDef;

import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends BaseGameActivity {


private Engine engine;
private Camera camera;
private Scene sahne;
private static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;
private static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 800; 
private Texture texSaha,texOyuncu1,texOyuncu2;
private TextureRegion texRegSaha,texRegOyuncu1,texRegOyuncu2;
private Sprite spriteSaha,spriteOyuncu1,spriteOyuncu2;
private Texture texAnime;
private TiledTextureRegion tiledTexReg;
private AnimatedSprite animSprite;

private PhysicsWorld physicsWorld;
private final FixtureDef fixDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f); 
private Body bodyOyuncu1;
private Body bodyOyuncu2;

public Engine onLoadEngine() {

    camera = new Camera(0,0,CAMERA_WIDTH,CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    final EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true,ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE, new FillResolutionPolicy(),camera);
    engineOptions.getTouchOptions().setRunOnUpdateThread(true); // dokunmatik ekranı ayrı bir thread ile kontrol ediyoruz
    engine = new Engine(engineOptions);


    return this.engine;

}

public void onLoadResources() {

    texSaha = new Texture(1024,512,TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
    this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(this.texSaha);
    texRegSaha = TextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.texSaha, this, "gfx/arkaplan3.png",0,0);

    texOyuncu1 = new Texture(128,128,TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
    texOyuncu2 = new Texture(128,128,TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);


    Texture textures[] = { texSaha,texOyuncu1,texOyuncu2 };

    this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTextures(textures);

    texRegOyuncu1 = TextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.texOyuncu1, this , "gfx/blue.png",0,0);
    texRegOyuncu2 = TextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.texOyuncu2, this , "gfx/yellow.png",0,0);


}

private float parmakKoordinatiX = 0;
private float parmakKoordinatiY = 0;
private boolean maviHareketEder = false;


public Scene onLoadScene() {
    this.sahne = new Scene();
    physicsWorld = new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2(SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH,0),false); 
    this.engine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());


    spriteSaha= new Sprite(0,0,texRegSaha);

    spriteOyuncu1 = new Sprite(600,CAMERA_HEIGHT/2 - 64, texRegOyuncu1);


    spriteOyuncu2 = new Sprite(50,CAMERA_HEIGHT/2 - 64, texRegOyuncu2);

    bodyOyuncu1 = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(physicsWorld, spriteOyuncu1, BodyType.DynamicBody, fixDef); 
    this.physicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(spriteOyuncu1, bodyOyuncu1,true,true,true,true)); 

    bodyOyuncu2 = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(physicsWorld, spriteOyuncu2, BodyType.DynamicBody, fixDef);
    this.physicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(spriteOyuncu2, bodyOyuncu2,true,true,true,true));

    bodyOyuncu1.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(-10,0));
    bodyOyuncu2.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(10,0));

    this.sahne.attachChild(spriteSaha);
    this.sahne.attachChild(spriteOyuncu1);
    this.sahne.attachChild(spriteOyuncu2);

    this.sahne.registerTouchArea(spriteOyuncu1);
    this.sahne.registerTouchArea(spriteOyuncu2);

    this.sahne.registerUpdateHandler(physicsWorld); 

    return this.sahne;
}

public void onLoadComplete() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



}
```

And this is my log:

```
02-02 08:28:37.527: I/dalvikvm(861): Could not find method     org.anddev.andengine.entity.shape.Shape.getVelocityX, referenced from method     org.anddev.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody
02-02 08:28:37.567: W/dalvikvm(861): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 5858:     Lorg/anddev/andengine/entity/shape/Shape;.getVelocityX ()F
02-02 08:28:37.567: D/dalvikvm(861): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x001f
02-02 08:28:37.567: D/dalvikvm(861): VFY: dead code 0x0022-0061 in     Lorg/anddev/andengine/extension/physics/box2d/PhysicsFactory;.createBoxBody     (Lorg/anddev/andengine/extension/physics/box2d/PhysicsWorld;Lorg/anddev/andengine/entity/sh   ape/Shape;Lcom/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/BodyDef$BodyType;Lcom/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/    FixtureDef;F)Lcom/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Body;
02-02 08:28:37.567: I/dalvikvm(861): Could not find method     org.anddev.andengine.entity.shape.Shape.getVelocityX, referenced from method     org.anddev.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody
02-02 08:28:37.567: W/dalvikvm(861): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 5858:     Lorg/anddev/andengine/entity/shape/Shape;.getVelocityX ()F
02-02 08:28:37.567: D/dalvikvm(861): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0027
02-02 08:28:37.567: D/dalvikvm(861): VFY: dead code 0x002a-0055 in     Lorg/anddev/andengine/extension/physics/box2d/PhysicsFactory;.createCircleBody     (Lorg/anddev/andengine/extension/physics/box2d/PhysicsWorld;Lorg/anddev/andengine/entity/sh    ape/Shape;Lcom/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/BodyDef$BodyType;Lcom/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/    FixtureDef;F)Lcom/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Body;
02-02 08:28:37.587: I/dalvikvm(861): Could not find method     org.anddev.andengine.entity.shape.Shape.getVelocityX, referenced from method     org.anddev.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsFactory.createPolygonBody
02-02 08:28:37.628: W/dalvikvm(861): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 5858:     Lorg/anddev/andengine/entity/shape/Shape;.getVelocityX ()F
02-02 08:28:37.628: D/dalvikvm(861): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x001d
02-02 08:28:37.628: D/dalvikvm(861): VFY: dead code 0x0020-0042 in     Lorg/anddev/andengine/extension/physics/box2d/PhysicsFactory;.createPolygonBody     (Lorg/anddev/andengine/extension/physics/box2d/PhysicsWorld;Lorg/anddev/andengine/entity/shape/Shape;    [Lcom/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector2;Lcom/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/BodyDef$BodyType;Lcom/badlogic/gdx/ph    ysics/box2d/FixtureDef;F)Lcom/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Body;
02-02 08:28:37.937: D/AndEngine(861): UpdateThread interrupted. Don't worry - this Exception is     most likely expected!
02-02 08:28:37.937: D/AndEngine(861): java.lang.InterruptedException
02-02 08:28:37.937: D/AndEngine(861):   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
02-02 08:28:37.937: D/AndEngine(861):   at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:358)
02-02 08:28:37.937: D/AndEngine(861):   at     org.anddev.andengine.engine.Engine$State.waitUntilCanUpdate(Engine.java:712)
02-02 08:28:37.937: D/AndEngine(861):   at     org.anddev.andengine.engine.Engine.yieldDraw(Engine.java:462)
02-02 08:28:37.937: D/AndEngine(861):   at     org.anddev.andengine.engine.Engine.onTickUpdate(Engine.java:453)
02-02 08:28:37.937: D/AndEngine(861):   at     org.anddev.andengine.engine.Engine$UpdateThread.run(Engine.java:675)
02-02 08:28:38.187: D/dalvikvm(861): Trying to load lib     /data/data/com.emredavarci.updatesistemi/lib/libandenginephysicsbox2dextension.so 0x405130b0
02-02 08:28:38.187: D/dalvikvm(861): Added shared lib     /data/data/com.emredavarci.updatesistemi/lib/libandenginephysicsbox2dextension.so 0x405130b0
02-02 08:28:38.187: D/dalvikvm(861): No JNI_OnLoad found in     /data/data/com.emredavarci.updatesistemi/lib/libandenginephysicsbox2dextension.so 0x405130b0,     skipping init
02-02 08:28:38.187: D/dalvikvm(861): GetMethodID: method not found:     Lcom/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/World;.preSolve:(JJ)V
02-02 08:28:38.187: W/dalvikvm(861): JNI WARNING: JNI method called with exception raised
02-02 08:28:38.187: W/dalvikvm(861):              in     Lcom/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/World;.newWorld (FFZ)J (GetMethodID)
02-02 08:28:38.187: W/dalvikvm(861): Pending exception is:
02-02 08:28:38.187: I/dalvikvm(861): Ljava/lang/NoSuchMethodError;: preSolve
02-02 08:28:38.197: I/dalvikvm(861):    at     com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.newWorld(Native Method)
02-02 08:28:38.197: I/dalvikvm(861):    at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.<init>    (World.java:78)
02-02 08:28:38.197: I/dalvikvm(861):    at     org.anddev.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsWorld.<init>(PhysicsWorld.java:56)
02-02 08:28:38.197: I/dalvikvm(861):    at     org.anddev.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsWorld.<init>(PhysicsWorld.java:52)
02-02 08:28:38.197: I/dalvikvm(861):    at     com.emredavarci.updatesistemi.MainActivity.onLoadScene(MainActivity.java:110)
02-02 08:28:38.197: I/dalvikvm(861):    at     org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.doResume(BaseGameActivity.java:158)
02-02 08:28:38.197: I/dalvikvm(861):    at     org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onWindowFocusChanged(BaseGameActivity.java:82)
02-02 08:28:38.197: I/dalvikvm(861):    at     com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onWindowFocusChanged(PhoneWindow.java:2001)
02-02 08:28:38.197: I/dalvikvm(861):    at     android.view.View.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(View.java:3924)
02-02 08:28:38.197: I/dalvikvm(861):    at     android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:659)
02-02 08:28:38.197: I/dalvikvm(861):    at     android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1968)
02-02 08:28:38.197: I/dalvikvm(861):    at     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-02 08:28:38.197: I/dalvikvm(861):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-02 08:28:38.197: I/dalvikvm(861):    at     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-02 08:28:38.197: I/dalvikvm(861):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-02 08:28:38.197: I/dalvikvm(861):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-02 08:28:38.197: I/dalvikvm(861):    at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-02 08:28:38.197: I/dalvikvm(861):    at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-02 08:28:38.197: I/dalvikvm(861):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-02 08:28:38.197: I/dalvikvm(861): "main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
02-02 08:28:38.197: I/dalvikvm(861):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4001f1a8 self=0xce48
02-02 08:28:38.197: I/dalvikvm(861):   | sysTid=861 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-1345006528
02-02 08:28:38.197: I/dalvikvm(861):   | schedstat=( 186996176 565732645 123 )
02-02 08:28:38.197: I/dalvikvm(861):   at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.newWorld(Native Method)
02-02 08:28:38.197: I/dalvikvm(861):   at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.<init>(World.java:78)
02-02 08:28:38.207: I/dalvikvm(861):   at     org.anddev.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsWorld.<init>(PhysicsWorld.java:56)
02-02 08:28:38.207: I/dalvikvm(861):   at     org.anddev.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsWorld.<init>(PhysicsWorld.java:52)
02-02 08:28:38.207: I/dalvikvm(861):   at     com.emredavarci.updatesistemi.MainActivity.onLoadScene(MainActivity.java:110)
02-02 08:28:38.207: I/dalvikvm(861):   at     org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.doResume(BaseGameActivity.java:158)
02-02 08:28:38.207: I/dalvikvm(861):   at     org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onWindowFocusChanged(BaseGameActivity.java:82)
02-02 08:28:38.207: I/dalvikvm(861):   at     com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onWindowFocusChanged(PhoneWindow.java:2001)
02-02 08:28:38.207: I/dalvikvm(861):   at     android.view.View.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(View.java:3924)
02-02 08:28:38.207: I/dalvikvm(861):   at     android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:659)
02-02 08:28:38.207: I/dalvikvm(861):   at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1968)
02-02 08:28:38.207: I/dalvikvm(861):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-02 08:28:38.207: I/dalvikvm(861):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-02 08:28:38.207: I/dalvikvm(861):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-02 08:28:38.207: I/dalvikvm(861):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-02 08:28:38.207: I/dalvikvm(861):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-02 08:28:38.207: I/dalvikvm(861):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-02 08:28:38.207: I/dalvikvm(861):   at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-02 08:28:38.207: I/dalvikvm(861):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-02 08:28:38.207: E/dalvikvm(861): VM aborting
```

What is wrong with this code?

Edit: I have tried not to use .jar files,Instead, I installed Git Plugin(GLES2) but this time,every methods name become changed.I mean I used to know onLoadResources(),but now Eclipse wants me onCreateResources() method. What is that? O.O

Comment: why you are using Jar files , why don't include the extensions as library projects?

Comment: i didn't get what you are saying. Shouldn't I add .jar files under /libs folder? (for example andengine.jar)

Comment: please, any ideas whats going wrong?

Comment: It says "Could not find method", means you haven't configured library into workspace.

Comment: But I did everything I know. Add .jar files to libraries,references. Do I need something else?

Comment: I edit my post,could you please look again :'(

Answer (score 3):

you will have to use the Box2DExtension library instead of using jar file directly, you can download it from the link given below:

https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension

Answer (score 0):

Get the Github plugin for Eclipse, and download the relevant AndEngine projects, then add these to your project's build path instead of the jar libraries.

Comment: Can you add more specifics to this answer? It's pretty weak as it stands.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.I tried to do so but this time all method names,imports etc. name is changed.For example onLoadResources() becomes onCreateResorces(). I don't know what to do